# Charged particle path concave in two directions

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

I am trying to model a charged particle path that is a series of crests (see image). I need the crests to be concave up in the y and z directions.

My configuration for each crest is currently
$$\vec{E}= \alpha*E_{y}\hat{x}+E_{y}\hat{y}+E_{z}\hat{z};  E{z}<<1$$
$$\vec{B}=B_{z}\hat{z}; B_{z}\in [3.45,4.7]$$

What can I add to make the growth in the z-direction more parabolic?

[image]